# TeXLive 2019 and Libertine: OpenType feature warnings

Tags: fonts, fontspec, libertine

Since I upgraded to TL2019, I get a lot of opentype feature warnings. For example for

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{libertine,fontspec}

\begin{document}
    ads
\end{document}
```

I get

```
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers= Monospaced, Lining'(fontspec) (tnum) not available for font 'LinLibertine_RZI'(fontspec) with script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers= Monospaced, Lining'(fontspec) (tnum) not available for font 'LinLibertine_RZI'(fontspec) with script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'LinBiolinum_RB' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
```

I my document I couldn't find where this could cause any issues to check whether there are some missing glyphs etc.
Is there a way to work around this?

---

EDIT: from `\listfiles` I get with Lualatex on linux:

```
 *File List*
    book.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
libertine.sty    2019/02/27 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fonts
for all LaTeX engines.
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
textcomp.sty    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.sty    2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2019-05-03 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2019-05-09 L3 programming layer (loader)
expl3-code.tex    2019-05-09 L3 programming layer
l3pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
fontspec-luatex.sty    2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
LinLibertine_R.tex
LinBiolinum_R.tex
LinBiolinum_K.tex
LinLibertine_I.tex
    LKey.tex
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: I don't get any warning.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your fast feedback. I added some information regarding the loaded/installed packages. Could it be related to one of these?

Comment: Which font is actually used? (see the end of the log-file).

Comment: Oh, I compiled with XeLaTeX. With LuaLaTeX the warnings do appear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer in one of the very last lines I find `</usr/share/fonts/ttf-linux-libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf>`

Comment: @bonanza that's not the libertine version from texlive. What happens if you move this fonts out of the way?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I removed an libterinus package that was installed and now it doesn't compile at all. The first error is `Package fontspec Error: The font "LinLibertine_R" cannot be found. \fi`. Looks like it doesn't look into texlive's font paths.

Comment: @bonanza `luaotfload` takes the system font in preference to the one in TeX Live, so if they're not aligned you can have problems. This is the reason for the warnings also on my side.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer egreg I followed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204438/34538 and now lualatex finds the TL fonts. It works without warnings now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am sorry, but what do you mean by `"move the fonts out of the way"`?. Would you please tell me how to do it on Win10 with MikTeX2.9? I mean what fonts are you talking about? and how to remove them?

Comment: @Diaa In my case, I had installed said font also system-wide, i.e., not only via TexLive (via my linux package manager). Once I removed them and cleaned the font cache (see linked post) it worked again. I suggest that check windows' fonts manager whether you have the same problem. If so, uninstall the fonts that are not installed through miktex.

Comment: @bonanza I am sorry, but I couldn't follow what you mean quite well. It would be great if you could give me specific steps to follow with the exact font names according to [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511325/2288).