# warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=RequiredOff' (rlig) not(fontspec) available

Tags: fonts, fontspec, warnings

What causes this warning, and how to get rid of it?

I believe that I have installed some packages that make this warning, but I couldn't figure out how to undo this damage.

P.S. I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Win 10.

> OpenType feature 'Ligatures=RequiredOff' (rlig) not(fontspec)
>   available for font 'LatinModernRoman' with script(fontspec)
>   'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{mathtools,mwe}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}
\setmainfont[
Ligatures={NoRequired,
    NoCommon,
    NoContextual}
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\biboptions{square,numbers,sort&compress}

\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latin Modern Roman has only two font features for ligatures:

```
otfinfo -f lmroman12-regular.otf | grep lig
```

has the output:

```
dlig    Discretionary Ligatures
liga    Standard Ligatures
```

If you do not want a warning then use:

```
\setmainfont[ Ligatures={NoCommon, % liga
                         NoRare,% dlig
}]{Latin Modern Roman}
```

Comment: Many thanks. May I know from where can I get the info you gave here?

Comment: The programm `otfinfo` comes with every TeX-Distribution. The features are explained in the documentation of `fontspec`

Comment: I ran this `otfinfo -f lmroman12-regular.otf | grep lig
` in the command prompt and got this`'otfinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Am I doing it right? Additionally, I would be grateful if you explained how can I know that `Latin Modern Roman` maps to `lmroman12-regular.otf`?

Comment: Which TeX distribution? Which operating system?

Comment: Miktex 2.9 on Win10

Comment: I have no experience with MiKTeX, but I suppose that MiKTeX do not install the font tools.

Comment: `otfinfo` is not part of the standard texlive installation on ubuntu either.

Comment: @Clément: Then simply install it ... : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lcdf-typetools

Comment: Yes, of course; I was just mentioning it since the discussion above said every TeX distribution.