# How to query font info/features using MiKTeX? [equivalent to otfinfo]

Tags: fonts, miktex

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511326/2288), the command `otfinfo`, coming with TeXLive, was used to query the font information.

However, I wonder if there is an equivalent one to be used in case of MiKTeX.

Comment: As far as I know; it hasn't this command, but you can install the  `lcdf type tools` independently.

Comment: You could make a feature request that miktex includes the tools too

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I created an issue on https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex asking for alternative way, and surprisingly I received an email that the issue had been deleted without prior notice.

Comment: @Diaa Sorry for that. The issue was semi-automatically closed (deleted) because it was not a self-contained report. I have created a new issue: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/457